# getJSON without showing the file path

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I was wondering if there was a way I can get a json file (currently using $.getJSON) without showing the get url in the 'view source'

Comment: No. I mean, you have to tell jQuery the URL somehow right? You could obfuscate it, e.g. encode and decode it as base64, but it's still trivial to deobfuscate the URL, or just watch the network monitor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really. I mean, you could derive it from something else via a complex function, but even then, it's there, just obscured.

And if you did, someone could just as easily snoop the file path using the browser's built-in diagnostic/debugging tools as they could from View Source (the "Network" tab in Chrome, for instance — all major modern browsers have debugging tools built in now). Here's me snooping on the path Stack Overflow uses to give details of upvotes/downvotes (for those with enough rep to see the breakdown):

[image]

Or they could use the debugger (see the "Scripts" tab) to inspect the string variable the calculation ended up with. Etc. Basically, if the browser knows enough to be able to retrieve the resource, the user can find out what that path was.

The only thing I can think of is to use a plug-in, like Flash or Java, to retrieve the resource and then display it. That would raise the bar *a little* (the path would still be accessible to anyone with a network analyzer or proxy).

Comment: What if the json was retrieved with a php file then passed on to a html/jquery/ajax page?

Comment: @echez: Then the client would see the URL of the PHP file. They'd also see the request to the PHP file and any data you sent with that request. If your goal is to make a URL that can only be fetched once, that's easily handled server-side with a unique, dynamically-allocated identifier that is consumed when served (via PHP or otherwise) and which expires after a period of time.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. Security through obscurity is never a chance.

You could make harder to reuse it by adding some referer check on the server side, though..
Or by using some "signature" token, etc.. (if you want to prevent people using it as a webservice).